# Read rows with different Width and several headers in R

Tags: r, transformation

I have the following log that I need to read in R

```
MO                RSITE                               COMB  FHOP  MODEL
RXOTG-0           3BFR42                              HYB   SY    G12

                  SWVERREPL      SWVERDLD       SWVERACT      TMODE
                                 B1312R078G     B1312R078G    SCM

MO                RSITE                               COMB  FHOP  MODEL
RXOTG-1           3BFR42                              HYB   SY    G12

                  SWVERREPL      SWVERDLD       SWVERACT      TMODE
                                 B1312R078G     B1312R078G    SCM
```

I need to read like that

```
MO      RSITE   COMB    FHOP    MODEL   SWVERREPL   SWVERDLD    SWVERACT    TMODE
RXOTG-0 3BFR42  HYB     SY      G12                 B1312R078G  B1312R078G  SCM
RXOTG-1 3BFR42  HYB     SY      G12                 B1312R078G  B1312R078G  SCM
```

I can't use read.fwf because each row has a differente width and every row has a header. The only way I could read is using read.table sep = " " and after heavy transformations I had the output wanted.

Someone has any suggestion to read with less coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some of the way by using `readLines` and then extracting lines, pasting them together and using the `text` argument in `read.table` to import the data.

```
f <- readLines("myFile.txt")
header  <- paste(f[1], f[3])
body <- sapply(seq(1, length(f), 6), function(i) paste(f[i+1], f[i+4]))

read.table(header = FALSE, text = paste(body, collapse = "\n"))
```

This omits the blank column. If you need this, or different columns are blank, use `read.fwf` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This will read your sample but will fail if any of the entries have unquoted embedded white space:

```
data.frame( scan(text=txt, 
                 what=list( MO="", RSITE="", COMB="",  FHOP="", 
                            MODEL="", SWVERREPL="",   SWVERDLD="", 
                            SWVERACT ="",   TMODE=""), 
                 multi.line=TRUE))[c(TRUE, FALSE), ] # removes extraneous extra "headers"
#--------------
Read 4 records
  MO RSITE COMB FHOP MODEL SWVERREPL SWVERDLD SWVERACT TMODE
1 MO RSITE COMB FHOP MODEL   RXOTG-0   3BFR42      HYB    SY
3 MO RSITE COMB FHOP MODEL   RXOTG-1   3BFR42      HYB    SY
```